# How to verify text using Squish

Tags: python, squish

I am automating a windows application using Squish. I am trying to verify if the required text is displayed in a window after I make some changes in the GUI. I used object spy to get the object ID, but I am confused how to give  a test verification point. The following Verification point  says in the results window as 'True' and 'True' are equal. But I want it to be as, for example 4X and 4X are equal.

```
test.compare(findObject("{name ='textObjective'}").enabled, True)
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `enabled` property, you can also compare any other property - e.g. the `text`:

```
test.compare(findObject("{name ='textObjective'}").text, "4X")
```

Comment: The recipe in my script keeps changing, so how do I compare the text for different tests? For example I have to test with different objectives like 4X, 20X, 0.30X etc.

Comment: @pigsrule You can use `test.verify` for that, e.g. `test.verify(any(findObject("{name ='textObjective'}").text in ["4X", "20X", "0.30X"]))`. In case you need to work with many different numeric values followed by 'X', a regular expression would be viable or some simple string manipulation. In either case, `test.verify` is your friend for populating the test report with the result.